# Why "vous pouvez LUI acheter une montre" when we are talking about a female person?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, genre, accord

I thought it should be “vous pouvez elle acheter une montre”.

Comment: It would be nice to have some historical explanation about that. For example in Italian the *lui* counterpart are *lui/gli* and *lei/le* which are different for masculine and feminine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Non, parce que [lui](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/lui) est ici un pronom personnel **des deux genres**, qui signifie *à lui* ou *à elle*.

Tu ne peux pas dire

> Vous pouvez elle acheter une montre. (**incorrect**)

Parce qu'il manque le *à*. Par exemple, on doit dire

> C'est à elle que vous pouvez acheter une montre.